# How to combine a one-dimensional array with a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of customer names:

```java
String[] customers = {"Joe Dirt", "John Dirt", "Josh Dirt"};
```

I also have a two-dimensional array that has acct numbers/payments:

```java
double[][] payments = {{1011,12,54,39},{1012,55,65,48},{1013,56,92,55}};
```

I need to match and print out the customer's name with their account and payments. The arrays are already sorted in order I just need to print out "Joe Dirt 1011, 12, 54, 55" and so on.. I'm trying to understand how to loop through the two-dimensional array.

This is what I have:

```java
public static ArrayList<String> combineArray(String[] customers,
                                             double[][] payments) {

    ArrayList<String> customerPayments = new ArrayList<String>();

    String result = "";
    String custName = "";
    String acctInfo = "";

    for (String n : customers) {
        custName = n;
        for (double[] x : payments) {
            for (double y : x) {
                acctInfo = String.valueOf(y);
            }
        }
        result = custName + acctInfo;
        customerPayments.add(result);
    }
    return customerPayments;
}
```

It's printing out the customer names correctly, but printing out only the last value of the payment two-dimensional array.
ex.

```
Joe Dirt55
John Dirt55
Josh Dirt55
```

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are number of approaches you could take. First, I suggest you program to the `List` interface (instead of the `ArrayList` concrete type). Second, use an explicit index in the first array so you can track your position in the `payments` array. Third, a `StringJoiner` might be useful for combining your elements. Something like,

```
public static List<String> combineArray(String[] customers, double[][] payments) {
    List<String> customerPayments = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
        for (double x : payments[i]) {
            sj.add(String.format("%.0f", x));
        }
        customerPayments.add(String.format("%s %s", customers[i], sj));
    }
    return customerPayments;
}
```

To make it easier to validate

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] customers = { "Joe Dirt", "John Dirt", "Josh Dirt" };
    double[][] payments = {
            { 1011, 12, 54, 39 },
            { 1012, 55, 65, 48 },
            { 1013, 56, 92, 55 }
    };
    combineArray(customers, payments).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And I get

```
Joe Dirt 1011, 12, 54, 39
John Dirt 1012, 55, 65, 48
Josh Dirt 1013, 56, 92, 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example:

```java
String[] customers = {"Joe Dirt", "John Dirt", "Josh Dirt"};
double[][] payments = {{1011,12,54,39},{1012,55,65,48},{1013,56,92,55}};
for (int i = 0; i < customers.length; i ++) {
    System.out.println(customers[i] + Arrays.toString(payments[i]));
}
```

or, if you want to see output strings without brackets try to do it:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(customers[i] + " " +
            Arrays.toString(payments[i]).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use an index in the `customers` cycle so you can use it to get the corresponding `payments`
2. you need to concatenate `acctInfo`, instead of replacing its value every time
3. you need to clear `acctInfo` at the start of the `customers` cycle so it does not accumulate the payments of the previous customers

For example:

```
public static ArrayList<String> combineArray(String[] customers, double[][] payments) {

    ArrayList<String> customerPayments = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
        String acctInfo = "";
        String custName = customers[i];
        for (double y : payments[i]) {
            acctInfo += String.valueOf(y);
        }
        String result = custName + acctInfo;
        customerPayments.add(result);
    }
    return customerPayments;
}
```